# Headers appear in browser but are missing in Response object

Tags: c#, .net, http-headers, response

I have a .NET application running on IIS 7.5 with the following response headers returned, as shown on Chrome's network page:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 3.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 21 Sep 2012 16:11:55 GMT
Content-Length: 840
```

In the C# code I try to read those response headers, but the only ones retrieved by `HttpContext.Response.Headers` are the following two:

- Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
- X-AspNetMvc-Version: 3.0

Needless to say, both `HttpContext.Response.Headers.AllKeys.Length` and `HttpContext.Response.Headers.Keys.Count` return 2.

Since in the production environment the application will have to read an extra response header, a dynamic one, I need to be able to intercept ALL those headers.

A solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the C# code on the server or on the client?

Comment: If the C# code is on the server, then the response is what you're returning. It's up to you to fill in the headers. If you don't, they'll get default/calculated values.

Answer (score 1):

Theses headers are `private` on IIS 7.5

You can add a `Response Header` by executing theses steps:

1. Open your `IIS Manager`, navigate to the level you want to manage.
2. In `Features View`, Double click `“HTTP Respond Headers”` feature.
3. Click “Add…” on the Actions Panel

Comment: That's what I had already tried in order to add the extra response header I mentioned before. That header comes up in Chrome's network page, together with the other headers, but `HttpContext.Response.Headers` comes up only with the two usual headers (`Server` and `X-AspNetMvc-Version`). What do you mean with headers being private on IIS 7.5?

Comment: you can't get private headers, they are non avaiable

Comment: Were you able to get the missing headers?